# cant vertical-align : text field with image in horizontal layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a search field similar to the one facebook has,
a text field and a button with search image for search.

markup

```
    <div>
        <div style="width: 250px;">
            <input id="txtSearchPerson" type="text" style="width:150px;float:left;" />
            <img id="btnSearch" src="search.png" style="float:left;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The two controls are horizontally aligned as I wanted.

The problem is the input(text field) right top is not aligned to image left top.

I can fix this with jq but I to handle it with CSS as it should be.

I tried playing with 'vertical-align' and other properties I know with no success.
I suspect the father container but still can't make it work for too long...

Please assist.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the top of the image and to the left of the image to make the formatting align as expected.

```
<div>
        <div style="width: 250px;">
            <input id="txtSearchPerson" type="text" style="width:150px;float:left;" />
            <img id="btnSearch" src="search.png" style="float:left;padding-top:.2em;padding-left: .1em;" />
        </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/umituz/2/edit

Comment: I don't want to relay on pixel because when I change the resolution aligment can be  changed.

Comment: You should not run into that issue with EM for the most part because it is relative to the font size you are currently using. Zooming in on the jsbin I made the image stayed aligned with the box. however I will look into another way to align them.  You can also use 1% in place of the .2em.

Comment: @GZ I checked how facebook does it and they have a <li><a><img> structure and they have fixed pixel hights for all of them.  Their image has a 3px 5px 3px 3px margin on it which holds the 23px by 23px image in the 31px tall <li>